# Ajax function not disabling form submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a contact form that cannot be submitted when the user enters too much text.

More specifically, an Ajax function disables the send button, preventing the form from being submitted when the character counter is in negative territory.

[image]

I made some changes to the code recently and now that function no longer works.

Not sure what the problem is. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

```js
// AJAX form messaging
$(function() {

    // get the form
    var form = $('#modal-contact-form');
    
    // get the messages element
    var formMessages = $('#modal-contact-form-responses');

    // set up event listener for contact form
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // disable html submit button
        e.preventDefault();
    
        // serialize form data
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
            
        // submit form using AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // make sure formMessages element has 'success' class
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');
            
            // set message text
            $(formMessages).text('Your message has been sent. Thank you!');
            
            // clear form
            $('input, textarea').val('');
            $("#modal-contact-form-message").trigger('change');         
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // make sure formMessages element has 'error' class
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // set the message text
            $(formMessages).text('Input error. Please review and re-submit.');
        });

    });

});

// text area character counter
// displays total characters allowed
// displays warning at defined count (currently 150)
// disables submit button when < 0
// max characters that can be input set by maxlength attribute in HTML
(function($) {

    $.fn.charCount = function(submit, options){

        this.submit = submit;

        // default configuration properties
        var defaults = {    
            allowed: 1250,      
            warning: 150,
            css: 'counter',
            counterElement: 'span',
            cssWarning: 'warning',
            cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
            counterText: ''
        }; 
    
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

        function calculate(obj,submit){
        
            submit.attr("disabled", "disabled");

            var count = $(obj).val().length;
            var available = options.allowed - count;
            if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssWarning);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssWarning);
            }
            if(available < 0){
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssExceeded);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
                submit.removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            
            $(obj).next().html(options.counterText + available);
        };
        
        this.each(function() {              
            $(this).after('<'+ options.counterElement +' class="' + options.css + '">'+ options.counterText +'</'+ options.counterElement +'>');
            
            calculate(this, submit);

            $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this,submit)});
            $(this).change(function(){calculate(this,submit)});
        });

    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#modal-contact-form-message").charCount($("#submit_cform"));
});
```

```css
/* textarea and character counter */

.modalDialog form > #counter-container {}

.modalDialog form > #counter-container > .counter {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif   
}
.modalDialog form > #counter-container .warning {
    color: orange;
}

.modalDialog form > #counter-container .warning::after {
    content: " approaching limit";
    font-size: 1em;
}

.modalDialog form > #counter-container .exceeded {
    color: red;
}

.modalDialog form > #counter-container .exceeded::after {
    content: " form won't submit";
    font-size: 1em;
}


/* success and error messages */

#modal-contact-form-responses,
#modal-subscription-form-messages {
    min-height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    margin: 5px 0; 
    font-size: .9em;
}

.success {
    color: black;
    background-color: #dff2bf;
}

.error {
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffbaba;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="modal-contact-form">

  <div>
    <label for="modal-contact-form-name">Name <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="name_cform" id="modal-contact-form-name" maxlength="75" required>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="modal-contact-form-email">E-mail <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="email" name="email_cform" id="modal-contact-form-email" maxlength="75" required>
  </div>

  <div id="subject-line">
    <label for="modal-contact-form-subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject_cform" id="modal-contact-form-subject" maxlength="75">
  </div>

  <div id="counter-container">
    <label for="modal-contact-form-message">Message <span>*</span></label>
    <textarea name="message_cform" id="modal-contact-form-message" maxlength="1500" cols="25" rows="5" required></textarea>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="formtarget_cform" value="modal" id="modal-contact-form-hidden">

  <button type="submit" name="submit_cform" id="modal-contact-form-submit">Send Message</button>

  <p id="modal-contact-form-responses"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: Surely you're able to debug this and at least give us an idea of what part of your code is not giving you the results you expect....

Comment: *I made some changes* - do you not have any form of source control?  Or maybe a deployed version you can refer back to?  Even a backup?

Comment: You have changed the `id` of your submit button from `submit_cform` to `modal-contact-form-submit` (or changed `.charCount($("#submit_cform"));` of course).  I suggest adding a check in your `fn`: `$.fn.charCount = function(submit, options){ if ($(submit).length === 0) alert("you dun messed up")...` (or similar...)

Comment: I've been staring at this code so long, and spent much of the night writing and debugging, that I didn't see a simple error. I used the `name` instead of the `id` attribute value in the script. Needed another pair of eyes. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
$("#modal-contact-form-message").charCount($("#submit_cform"));
```

To this instead

```
$("#modal-contact-form-message").charCount($("#modal-contact-form-submit"));
```